# React how to pass react array selected array data one component to another component

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json, use-effect

**I want to select one person's data like this:**

***JSON data file***

```
{
    "person": [

      {
        "id": "userId",
        "sellerImage": "https://i.pravatar.cc/300",
        "lastOnline": "Date of last online",
        "sellerName": "Ryann Remo",
        "isOnline": true,
        "lastSeenDate": "Today",
        "product":"Rough Shirt",
        "messages": [
          {
            "id": "messageId",
            "userId": "userIdOfUser",
            "message": "Message text 01",
            "date": "Date of message",
            "isRead": false
          },
          {
            "id": "messageId",
            "userId": "userIdOfSeller",
            "message": "Message text 02",
            "date": "Date of message",
            "isRead": true
          },
          {
            "id": "messageId",
            "userId": "userIdOfSeller",
            "message": "Message text",
            "date": "Date of message 03",
            "isRead": false
          }
        ]
      },

      {
        "id": "userId",
        "sellerImage": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d50",
        "lastOnline": "Date of last online",
        "sellerName": "Karp Bonolo",
        "isOnline": true,
        "lastSeenDate": "Yesterday",
        "product":"Rough Shirt",
        "messages": [
          {
            "id": "messageId",
            "userId": "userIdOfUser",
            "message": "Message text",
            "date": "Date of message",
            "isRead": false
          },
          {
            "id": "messageId",
            "userId": "userIdOfSeller",
            "message": "Message text",
            "date": "Date of message",
            "isRead": true
          },
          {
            "id": "messageId",
            "userId": "userIdOfSeller",
            "message": "Message text",
            "date": "Date of message",
            "isRead": false
          }
        ]
      }
]
}
```

***importing data from the above JSON file....***

```
  const person = AdminConversationData.person.map((data) => {
    return {
      ...data,
    };
  });
```

***selecting specific person data like this***

```
<RadioGroup>
  <div className="space-y-2">
    {person.map((item, idx) => (
      <RadioGroup.Option
        key={item}
        value={item}
        className={({ active }) =>
          `${
            active
              ? 'ring-2 ring-offset-2 ring-offset-red-300 ring-white ring-opacity-60 border-l-4 border-red-500'
              : ''
          }
            relative rounded-lg shadow-md px-5 py-4 cursor-pointer flex focus:outline-none entry cursor-pointer 
            transform hover:scale-105 duration-300`
        }
      >
          <>
        <div className="flex-2">
          <div className="w-12 h-12 relative">
            <img
              className="w-12 h-12 rounded-full mx-auto"
              src={"https://picsum.photos/200"}
              alt="chat-user"
            />
            <span className="absolute w-4 h-4 bg-gray-400 rounded-full right-0 bottom-0 border-2 border-white"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1 px-2">
          <div className="truncate w-32">
            <span className="text-gray-800">{item.sellerName}</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <small className="text-gray-600">Yea, Sure!</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-2 text-right">
          <div>
            <small className="text-gray-500">{item.lastSeenDate}</small>
          </div>
          <div>
            <small className="text-xs bg-red-500 text-white rounded-full h-6 w-6 leading-6 text-center inline-block">
              23
            </small>
          </div>
        </div>
          </>
      
      </RadioGroup.Option>
    ))}
  </div>
</RadioGroup>
```

***and... what I need to do is if I select specific person data I need to pass the personal data into another place on this page***

***as an example***

```
<>
 <div class="relative">
    <span class="absolute text-green-500 right-0 bottom-0">
       <svg width="20" height="20">
          <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="8" fill="currentColor" class="absolute right-0 w-4 h-4 bg-green-600 border-2 border-green-700 rounded-full top-2 animate-pulse"></circle>
       </svg>
    </span>
 <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549078642-b2ba4bda0cdb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=3&amp;w=144&amp;h=144" alt="" class="w-10 sm:w-16 h-10 sm:h-16 rounded-full"/>
 </div>
 <div class="flex flex-col leading-tight">
    <div class="text-2xl mt-1 flex items-center">
       <span class="text-gray-700 mr-3">name</span>
    </div>
    <span class="text-lg text-gray-600">Seller</span>
</div>
</>
```

***above selected person data I want to pass this section to relevant places (ex: the name should be selected person name)  how can I do that?***

Answer (score 0):

If the component is a child component you could just initialize a state in the parent component holding the selected person:

```
const [selectedPerson, setSelectedPerson] = useState(null);
```

You will need to handle the `onChange` event to select a person:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const pers = person.find(p => p.id === e.target.value)
    setSelectedPerson(pers)
}

...

{person.map((item, idx) => (
      <RadioGroup.Option
        key={item.id}
        value={item.id}
        onChange={handleChange}
        ...
```

Then, pass it to the child component as a prop.
Declare your child component to retrieve the properties you need:

```
const ChildComponent = ({ name }) => {
    return (
        <>
        <div class="relative">
            <span class="absolute text-green-500 right-0 bottom-0">
            <svg width="20" height="20">
                <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="8" fill="currentColor" class="absolute right-0 w-4 h-4 bg-green-600 border-2 border-green-700 rounded-full top-2 animate-pulse"></circle>
            </svg>
            </span>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549078642-b2ba4bda0cdb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=3&amp;w=144&amp;h=144" alt="" class="w-10 sm:w-16 h-10 sm:h-16 rounded-full"/>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col leading-tight">
            <div class="text-2xl mt-1 flex items-center">
            <span class="text-gray-700 mr-3">{name}</span>
            </div>
            <span class="text-lg text-gray-600">Seller</span>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

And pass them using:

```
<ChildComponent {...selectedPerson} />
```

If you need to pass the selected person down multiple levels you may wanna use the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#api).

Comment: Can we do this with useEffect ?

Comment: You could use `useEffect` if you need to perform operations when the `selectedPerson` is changing. From my understanding of your problem, this is not what you need.

Comment: I'm using this for the chat page, to change the chat box name according to the selected chat. can you help me with "useEffect" to solve this problem?